# Windows Server: Activation ID, Application ID, Installation ID and Product ID?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I need a way to identify Windows Server installs on a server. A server could be running multiple instances of Windows Server. I need an ID which is unique to each install.

If I run `slmgr.vbs /dlv` I can see a few IDs. I think I can use one of these, I just can't find documentation on what each one is.

What are each one of these: Activation ID, Application ID, Installation ID and Product ID? Which of these can change if Windows is reactivated, reinstalled, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need a way to identify Windows Server installs on a server.

That's the InstallID.

> Which of these can change if Windows is reactivated, reinstalled, etc?

All of them. Do you want to identify an *installation* or a *hardware environment*?

The only thing that does not change when software (Windows Server, for example) is reinstalled, is the hardware. It's not easy to find a solution for that (identifying hardware setups uniquely); IDs will change when CPUs are changed, memory is added or defective components are swapped.

You can identify ONE complete installation, but not if it's reinstalled (then that would be another ONE installation).